# Can't see what command started Windows program through python

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, psutil

I have a program that I start through a python program using `Psutil.Popen` and the program starts fine.

When the program that started the windows process crashes I want to find the program through the command that I used before. If the process isn't running then I start it.

I can access the command of other programs like chrome, but the `p.cmdline()` of the started process always returns empty.

Here is the code I have that checks the running processes:

```
def processExists(name, command):
    # name = "chrome.exe"
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            procName = proc.name()
            if name in procName:
                cmdline = proc.cmdline()
                if command in cmdline:
                    return (proc, cmdline)
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            print "Permission error or access denied on purpose"
```

I have tried to run it as an administrator, but that hasn't solved the issue. Is it a permission issue, or something else entirely?

Comment: I figured out that it can't load a 64bit program's image and thus can't get the command line information for those programs. It works fine if the program is 32bit.

Comment: Installing a 64bit version of python 2.7 allows the program to look at both 32bit and 64bit programs.